# How to convert xml that possibly contains lists to dict in python?

Tags: python, arrays, xml, dictionary, lxml

I have found some solutions in converting xml to dict but they don't solve the possibility of having a list in the xml.
For example, my xml:

```
<Body>
    <Count>3</Count>
    <Books>
        <Book>
            <Title>Book 1</Title>
            <Author>Author 1</Author>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Book 2</Title>
            <Author>Author 2</Author>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Book 3</Title>
            <Author>Author 3</Author>
        </Book>
    </Books>
    <Details>
        <Errors>0</Errors>
    </Details>
</Body>
```

code: (slightly modified version of https://gist.github.com/jacobian/795571 )

```
def elem2dict(node):
    """
    Convert an lxml.etree node tree into a dict.
    """
    d = {}
    for e in node.iterchildren():
        key = e.tag.split('}')[1] if '}' in e.tag else e.tag
        if e.text is None:
            continue
        value = e.text if e.text.strip() else elem2dict(e)
        d[key] = value
    return d
```

result:

```
{
    'Count': '3',
    'Books': {
        'Book': {
            'Title': 'Book 3',
            'Author': 'Author 3'
        }
    },
    'Details': {
        'Errors': '0'
    }
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
    'Count': '3',
    'Books':
    [
        { 
            'Title': 'Book 1',
            'Author': 'Author 1'
        },
        { 
            'Title': 'Book 2',
            'Author': 'Author 2'
        },
        { 
            'Title': 'Book 3',
            'Author': 'Author 3'
        }
    ],
    'Details': {
        'Errors': '0'
    }
}
```

Notes:

- the list isn't always labeled `Books` or `Book` but can be any tag with this structure.
- I need to exclude the xml attributes as it is currently impllemented

Comment: I think you're looking for this library, it works like a charm for me: https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [ElementsTree XML](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) API for this?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('book.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print str(child.tag) + " " + str(child.text)
    for child2 in child:
        print "  " + str(child2.tag) + " " + str(child2.text)
        for child3 in child2:
            print "      " + str(child3.tag) + " " + str(child3.text)
```

And result:

```
Count 3
Books 

  Book 

      Title Book 1
      Author Author 1
  Book 

      Title Book 2
      Author Author 2
  Book 

      Title Book 3
      Author Author 3
Details 

  Errors 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The output is not exactly in line with your requirement, but it takes care of arrays of multiple types within the same parent. The idea is to check if the key exists and convert it to an array if it does.

```
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = value
    elif type(d[key]) is list:
        # already an array, append
        d[key].append(value)
    else:
        # second item with same key: 
        # change the item at `key` to an array retaining
        # the existing item.
        d[key] = [d[key], value]
```

This gives:

```
{'Books': {'Book': [{'Author': 'Author 1', 'Title': 'Book 1'},
                {'Author': 'Author 2', 'Title': 'Book 2'},
                {'Author': 'Author 3', 'Title': 'Book 3'}]},
 'Count': '3',
 'Details': {'Errors': '0'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a easy solution base on `lxml` library. And also makes the results in OrderedDict. see [Github](https://github.com/shnode/xml2dict)

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
from collections import OrderedDict

###########################
# xml to dict
###########################

def xml2dict(fpath):
   """"""
    with open(fpath, 'rb') as f:
        # tree type:lml.etree._ElementTree
        tree = etree.parse(f)
        # tree.getroot() type:tree.getroot(), xml.etree._Element
        return tree2dict(tree.getroot())


def tree2dict(node):
    """"""
    subdict = OrderedDict({})
    # iterate over the children of this element--tree.getroot
    for e in node.iterchildren():
        d = tree2dict(e)
        for k in d.keys():
            # handle duplicated tags
            if k in subdict:
                v = subdict[k]
        # use append to assert exception
                try:
                    v.append(d[k])
                    subdict.update({k:v})
                except AttributeError:
                    subdict.update({k:[v,d[k]]})
            else:
                subdict.update(d)
    if subdict:
        return {node.tag: subdict}
    else:
        return {node.tag: node.text}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print xml2dict('test.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you try to make list of dictionaries, then it might work as u need. Try the following

```
def elem2dict(node):
    """
    Convert an lxml.etree node tree into a dict.
    """
    lis = []
    for e in node.iterchildren():
        d = {}
        key = e.tag.split('}')[1] if '}' in e.tag else e.tag
        if e.text is None:
            continue
        value = e.text if e.text.strip() else elem2dict(e)
        d[key] = value
        lis.append(d)
    return lis
```

it gives

```
[{'Count': '3'},
 {'Books': [{'Book': [{'Title': 'Book 1'}, {'Author': 'Author 1'}]},
            {'Book': [{'Title': 'Book 2'}, {'Author': 'Author 2'}]},
            {'Book': [{'Title': 'Book 3'}, {'Author': 'Author 3'}]}]},
 {'Details': [{'Errors': '0'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmltodict` lib. The following snippet works nicely with less effort:

```
import xmltodict
with open(file) as fd:
    xml = fd.read()
    xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml)
```

For the list of items, this lib already parses as follow:

```
list_books = xml_dict['Body']['Books']['Book']
book_0 = list_books[0]
book_1 = list_books[1]
```

Hope this help!